# How to convert an SSIS package to SQL Server 2000 DTS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, dts, ssis

Is it possible to create a dtsx package in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio then convert it to a dts 2000 package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SSIS packages have a broader range of facilities than DTS. You'd have to re-author the package (as best you can) using Enterprise Manager.